# Extracting a datetime from a string and checking the value

Tags: c#, regex, datetime

Ok, the method for extracting a date looks like this:

```
public DateTime ExtractDateTime(string log)
{
    var regex = new Regex(@"\d{4}.\d{2}.\d{2} \d{2}.\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4}");
    var match = regex.Match(log);
    return match.Success ? DateTime.ParseExact(match.Value, "yyyy.MM.dd hh:mm:ss:ffff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) : new DateTime();
}
```

The log file looks like this:

> "2018.07.26 10:33:05:0927: ECOM - New Session Requested... Success (Start Session Thread Started)",

I have created a test that makes sure the `DateTime` that is extracted is correct. The test method looks like this:

```
[Test]
public void CanExtractDate()
{
    // Assemble
    var service = TroposContext.GivenServices();
    var log = service.WhenCreateLog("ECOM - New Session Requested... Success (Start Session Thread Started)", 2018, 7, 26, 10, 33, 5, 927, out var actualDate);

    // Act
    var dateTime = service.LogValidator.ExtractDateTime(log);
    var compare = dateTime.CompareTo(actualDate);

    // Assert
    compare.Should().Be(0);
}
```

And it is failing because `compare` is actually -1.
The method `WhenCreateLog` has an out `DateTime` parameter which is created by the parameters sent to the method. That method looks like this:

```
public string WhenCreateLog(string log, int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute, int second, int millisecond, out DateTime actualDate)
{
    var request = $"{year}.{month.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0')}.{day.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0')} {hour.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0')}:{minute.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0')}:{second.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0')}:{millisecond.ToString().PadLeft(4, '0')}: {log}";
    actualDate = new DateTime(year, month, day, hour, minute, second, millisecond);
    return request;
}
```

So, when examining both dates, I can see that the `dateTime` variable has milliseconds equal to 92, whereas `actualDate` is 927.
The `actualDate` is correct, why is `dateTime` showing it incorrectly?

Comment: How are you instantiating actualDate?

Comment: `actualDate = new DateTime(year, month, day, hour, minute, second, millisecond);`

Comment: Sorry, I see it now

Comment: Note: the dot symbol `.` in regex matches any symbol. To match exactly the dot you need to apply the escaping: `\.`. So, regex may look like this: `@"\d{4}\.\d{2}\.\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{4}"`.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that when creating it. But tbh, that is fine in this case :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured this out. It looks like `new DateTime()` millisecond is between 0-999. But my string is using 4 digits. `DateTime.ParseExact` allows me to have any value, so I had to make sure both methods were using the same `ParseExact`. So I changed my **LogValidator** method to this:

```
public const string Format = "yyyy.MM.dd hh:mm:ss:ffff";
public DateTime ExtractDateTime(string log)
{
    var regex = new Regex(@"\d{4}.\d{2}.\d{2} \d{2}.\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4}");
    var match = regex.Match(log);
    return match.Success ? DateTime.ParseExact(match.Value, Format, null) : new DateTime();
}
```

and then I changed my **WhenCreateLog** method to this:

```
public string WhenCreateLog(string log, int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute, int second, int millisecond, out DateTime actualDate)
{
    var dateString = $"{year}.{month.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0')}.{day.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0')} {hour.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0')}:{minute.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0')}:{second.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0')}:{millisecond.ToString().PadLeft(4, '0')}";
    var request = $"{dateString}: {log}";
    actualDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, LogValidator.Format, null);
    return request;
}
```

and that works

Comment: Yeah, was about to post it. It was better if you just use 3 places instead of four to your miliseconds. Also, you could simplify your `request` just puting actualDate first and using it's string overload `actualDate.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss:fff")` that way you don't need the huge string format thing you're using

Comment: Also, note that only because your match was successful, it doesn't mean that `DateTime.ParseExact` will succed, as this passes your regex but is an invalid date: `"9999.99.99 99.99.99.9999"`

Comment: I would like to use 3 places :) but it all comes from a log file of which I have no control over :(

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to keep the four places, you could just have change the miliseconds `PadLeft` to `PadRight` and it would be ok. Another option is to use the `DateTime.ToString()` overload, just changing the order of your statements:

Option 1:

```
var dateString = $"{year}.{month.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0')}.{day.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0')} {hour.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0')}:{minute.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0')}:{second.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0')}:{millisecond.ToString().PadRight(4, '0')}";
```

Option 2:

```
actualDate = new DateTime(year, month, day, hour, minute, second, millisecond);
var request = $"{actualDate.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss:ffff")}: {log}";
```

Also, you should check if the Date is valid and probably you're better using the static Regex.Match instead of an instance, as the static method caches the pattern to speed up future uses:

```
public DateTime ExtractDateTime(string log)
{
    string pattern = @"\d{4}.\d{2}.\d{2} \d{2}.\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4}";
    var match = Regex.Match(log, pattern);
    DateTime parsedDate;
    if(DateTime.TryParseExact(match.Value, "yyyy.MM.dd hh:mm:ss:ffff",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDate))
    {
        return parsedDate;
    }
    return new DateTime();
}

public string WhenCreateLog(string log, int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute, int second, int millisecond, out DateTime actualDate)
{
    actualDate = new DateTime(year, month, day, hour, minute, second, millisecond);
    var request = $"{actualDate.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss:ffff")}: {log}";
    //Or
    //var request = $"{year}.{month.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0')}.{day.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0')} {hour.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0')}:{minute.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0')}:{second.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0')}:{millisecond.ToString().PadRight(4, '0')}";
    return request;
}
```

Comment: This didn't work, when I run my test I get Message: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException : Valid values are between 0 and 999, inclusive.
Parameter name: millisecond

Comment: That is why I changed the format myself and made it a public constant